# Recuperar variable tras préstamo en Rust

Tags: rust, alcance

Estoy aprendiendo Rust, y hay una situación que no logro entender con respecto al préstamo de variables. Se supone que cuando una variable se presta de forma mutable a otra, al salir de alcance la segunda, se recupera el uso de la misma por la primera.

Por eso este código compila:

```
    fn main() {
    let mut un_valor = "3";
    {
        let mut un_vector = Vec::new();
        un_vector.push(&mut un_valor); // un_valor es prestado a un_vector
    } // un_vector sale de alcance
    println!("{}", un_valor);
}
```

Sin embargo, si añadimos una capa de complejidad, el código deja de compilar:

```
struct Contenedor<'a>{
    vector: Vec<&'a mut &'a str>
}
fn main() {
    let mut un_valor = "3";
    {
        let mut un_vector = Vec::new();
        un_vector.push(&mut un_valor);
        let _contenedor = Contenedor{vector: un_vector};
    }
    println!("{}", un_valor);
}
```

Aparece el siguiente error:

```
Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `un_valor` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:11:20
   |
8  |         un_vector.push(&mut un_valor);
   |                        ------------- mutable borrow occurs here
...
11 |     println!("{}", un_valor);
   |                    ^^^^^^^^
   |                    |
   |                    immutable borrow occurs here
   |                    mutable borrow later used here
```

Me gustaría entender lo que está pasando, y en concreto por qué no puedo usar un_valor si las variables que lo tenían prestado ya no existen.

Comment: No soy experto en rust, pero me parece que el problema lo tienes al dar el mismo _tiempo de vida_ al campo `vector` que a los elementos de este vector.. Al crear la estructura `contenedor` estás asociando su tiempo de vida a la de `un_valor`, por lo que no desaparecerá `un_vector` al final del bloque y, por tanto, no terminará el préstamo. Intenta usar dos tiempo de vida: `struct Contenedor<'a,'b>{ vector: Vec<&'a mut &'b str> }`.